# Oracle Apex arabic language loading

Tags: oracle-apex

When using load_ar.sql script , the arabic language does not displays as option on login page like other languages. Also it seems that it does not perform lengthy loading like other language.

Does apex gets arabic support using load_ar.sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using load_ar.sql script , the arabic language does not displays
> as option on login page like other languages.

This is expected behaviour.  We translate the Oracle APEX App Builder to 9 standard languages: French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese (Brazil), Simplified Chinese, Spanish, and Traditional Chinese. When you install all languages in your instance, you should only expect to see these 9 language options available for selection on your instance login page.

With APEX 21.2, we introduced support for the translation of our Runtime Messages to  31 languages, including Arabic.  Please refer to the following sections of our documentation:

- [4.1.9 Translation of Runtime Messages into 31 Languages](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-8CE66A34-3C35-40EF-9E14-62A1100E4851) in the APEX 21.2 Release Notes.
- [6.9.1 About Installing Translated Versions of Oracle APEX](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmig/installing-translated-versions-of-apex.html#GUID-D14592D7-CB4C-411B-B1AB-724FCEE22BEF) in the APEX 21.2 Installation Guide.

> Also it seems that it does not perform lengthy loading like other
> language.

I believe you are referring to the length of time it takes to install, say German, versus Arabic? The reason the latter is quicker is because it is just installing Runtime Messages.  When you install one of our Standard 9 languages, that is installing all of the internal apps in that language, e.g. App Builder, SQL Workshop, etc, in that language - and therefore takes longer to complete that installation.

So once you have run the install script to install Arabic on your APEX instance, those translations will be available to use in your own APEX apps.  For example, create an app with an Interactive Report. Edit the application, and navigate to Edit Application Definition > Globalization, and change the Application Default Language to 'Arabic (ar)'. Save that change and run your app.  You should see the Interactive Report Actions menu items all displayed in Arabic. Please note that string created by the Create Wizards, such as button labels or success messages, will be in the language of the App Builder and should not be expected to be translated in to Arabic.  We hope to address that gap in a future release of APEX.